# Unknown provider: ngModelProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to inject `ngModel` in an Angular directive and I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngModelProvider <- ngModel
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/unpr?p0=ngModelProvider%20%3C-%20ngModel
    at http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3741:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3869:39)
    at http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3746:45
    at getService (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3869:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3896:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:3917:23)
    at $get (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:7201:28)
    at http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:6592:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:2013/Scripts/angular.js:327:20) angular.js:9937
(anonymous function) angular.js:9937
$get angular.js:7283
$get.Scope.$digest angular.js:12414
$get.Scope.$apply angular.js:12660
done angular.js:8272
completeRequest angular.js:8477
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Here is my directive:

```
module.directive("myDatePicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: '<p class="input-group" title="{{title}}">' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" data-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" ng-model="selectedDate" data-is-open="isOpen" data-datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" data-close-text="{{closeText}}" />' +
                            '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>' +
                            '</span>' +
                        '</p>',
        replace: true,
        require: '?ngModel',
        //priority: 0,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            selectedDate: "=ngModel",
            onChange: "&",
            dateFormat: "="
        },
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            // Correct ngModel for isolate scope
            if (tAttrs.ngModel) {
                tAttrs.$set('selectedDate', tAttrs.ngModel, false);
                tAttrs.$set('ngModel', 'selectedDate', false);
            }

            return {
                post: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    // Render
                    return controller.$render = function () {
                        if (!controller.$viewValue) {
                            return;
                        }
                        angular.extend(scope, controller.$viewValue);
                    };
                }
            };
        },
        priority: 100,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        },
        controller: function ($scope, global, ngModel) {
            $scope.isOpen = false;
            $scope.closeText = 'Close';
            $scope.dateOptions = {};

            $scope.open = function ($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.isOpen = true;
            };

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $scope.selectedDate;
            },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('required', newValue == true);
                    $scope.onChange({ newDate: newValue, oldDate: oldValue });
                }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
                    <input data-my-date-picker
                           id="EventDatePicker" data-name="EventDatePicker"
                           data-date-format="dateFormat"
                            ng-model="EventDetails.Date"
                           ng-required="true"
                           data-title="Date" />
```

Why can't it be resolved?
I have tried doing this:

```
module.directive("myDatePicker", ['ngModel', function () {
```

...but it didn't help.

I have also tried removing `priority` and it didn't help either.

Is it something related to the order that directives get loaded?

What am I missing here?

Any ideas?

---

Finally I did this, according to sma's suggestion:

```
        require: ['^ngModel'/*, '^isDate'*/],
        scope: {
            title: "@?",
            name: "@?"
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel/*, isDate*/) {
        ...
```

This kind of seems to work.

I am not sure why I cannot inject this in the controller. :(

There must be a way, but I haven't found it yet...

But for some strange reason, directives like the `isDate` above still are not injected (although they are defined before the current directive).

This is confusing.

Comment: One observation: it should be `require` not `requires` for requiring a directive.

Comment: @scarlz I have fixed this. But nothing changes.

Comment: is EventDetails.Date actually set?

Comment: @Baszz Yes, but I think that even when not set, it should still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your arguments are wrong in your controller function.  The controller function accepts:

```
controller : function ($scope, $element) {
   ...    
}
```

If you are trying to inject ngModel as a dependency, use the link function instead:

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to work. I wonder how you can do the same in the controller. But I think that you are wrong about the controller. For the controller, the arguments get injected automatically by Angular and they have no particular order (I don't know how Angular does this, but it happens!). The link function is different (it has an order). Thanks! :)

Comment: The controller accepts whatever instance dependencies you require. It is no different from an ordinary Controller, except that you can inject [some extra things](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-) a normal Controller can't depend on, like $attr, $element and $transclude.